# Using pdfliteral to highlight text

Tags: color, luatex, highlighting, lua

Using `pdfliteral`, one can color text like the following:

```
      w1_prev = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
      w1_prev.data = "q 1 0 0 rg"
      w1_prev.mode = 1

      w2_prev = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
      w2_prev.data = "Q"
      w2_prev.mode = 1

      node.insert_after(prev_line.prev,prev_line.prev,w1_prev) --color text between prev_line.prev...
      node.insert_before(prev_line,prev_head,w2_prev) -- and prev_head
```

Is there a code similar to `q 1 0 0 rg` which highlights text instead of coloring the letters?

Comment: By 'highlight', do you mean a 'marker-pen' like background?

Comment: @JosephWright yes, indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is more appropriate on a PDF q&a site :)

You can draw PDF boxes with the code I posted in [my answer to the one letter word](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/one-letter-word-at-the-end-of-line/28128#28128) problem. Just be sure to put the `pdf_literal` at the beginning of the text, so the text is on top of that box.

Comment: Right, I know about the boxes (from reading and using your code), but what I would like to achieve is to highlight the text :-)

Comment: At least at the TeX level, 'highlighting' is always done by boxing material up, as you can only set the background of a box, not of particular text.