# Problem with impnattypo package

Tags: packages, luatex, typography

I'm using impnattypo package with nosingleletter option under TeXLive 2016. With no luck.

I want to move last 'single letter' word to another line. 
Examples in [one-letter word at the end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/one-letter-word-at-the-end-of-line/) also doesn't work.

Here's minimal example (take a look at the letter 'a' at the end of the first line).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[nosingleletter]{impnattypo}
\begin{document}
\Blindtext
\end{document}
```

Comment: `LuaTeX` internals changed quite a lot in the current version, it seems that `impnattypo` package needs to be updated in order to support these changes

Comment: Can anyone fix `LuaTeX` support in `impnattypo` package? https://github.com/raphink/impnattypo/issues/6