# One-letter word at the end of the line

Tags: xetex, line-breaking, cyrillic

Russian typographic rules (or good practices) say that:

- it is very bad to leave at the end of the line a one-letter word, starting the sentence,
- it is better not to leave at the end of the line a one-letter conjunction.

Usually the first case is solved by replacement of `([ \n\t«„]+)([АВИКОСУЯ][,]*)([ \n\t]+)` to `$1$2~`, e. g. `«А, дорогой друг!»` becomes `«А,~дорогой друг!»`

Probably it is possible to introduce some other sign (especially using Unicode) for “optional no-line-break”, something like this:

```
 \newunicodechar{¬}{\penalty500\ }
```

I know about [impnattypo](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/impnattypo) as LuaTeX solution (discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/one-letter-word-at-the-end-of-line)), but I am looking for XeLaTeX solution. And `impnattypo` has at least to be modified for my needs to make difference between small and capital letters.

P.S. There are also some old but still used [rules](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/427565/%D0%A0%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5-%D0%90-%D0%92-%D0%98-%D0%9A-%D0%9E-%D0%A1-%D0%A3-%D0%AF) that even multi-letter conjunction in the beginning of the sentence cannot stay at the end of the line. Here is a grep that might be useful for somebody: `(А|Абы|Аж|Ай|Аки|Ако|Али|Аль|Ан|Аще|Без|Безо|Благо|Благодаря|Близ|Близко|Бо|Буде|Будто|В|Вблизи|Ввиду|Вглубь|Вдогон|Вдоль|Ведь|Взамен|Включая|Вкруг|Вместо|Вне|Внизу|Внутри|Внутрь|Во|Вовнутрь|Возле|Вокруг|Вопреки|Вослед|Впереди|Вплоть|Впредь|Впрочем|Вразрез|Вроде|Вслед|Вследствие|Всё|Где|Да|Дабы|Даже|Для|До|Докуда|Дотоле|Егда|Едва|Еже|Ежели|Если|Ж|Же|За|Заместо|Зане|Занеже|Зато|Зачем|Значит|И|Ибо|Из|Изнутри|Изо|Или|Иль|Именно|Имже|Иначе|Инда|Исключая|Исходя|Итак|К|Кабы|Как|Каков|Какой|Касательно|Ко|Когда|Когды|Коли|Коль|Который|Кроме|Кругом|Куда|Ли|Либо|Лицом|Лишь|Ль|Меж|Между|Мимо|На|Наверху|Навроде|Навстречу|Над|Надо|Назад|Назади|Накануне|Наместо|Наперекор|Наперерез|Наподобие|Напротив|Наряду|Настолько|Насупротив|Насчёт|Начиная|Не|Невзирая|Недалеко|Нежели|Независимо|Несмотря|Ни|Ниже|Но|О|Об|Обаче|Обо|Обок|Однако|Около|Окрест|Окромя|Округ|Опосля|Опричь|От|Отколь|Откуда|Откудова|Относительно|Ото|Оттого|Отчего|Перед|Передо|По|Поблизости|Поверх|Под|Подле|Подо|Подобно|Поелику|Позади|Позднее|Пока|Покамест|Покаместь|Покеда|Помимо|Понеже|Поперёд|Поперёк|Порядка|Посверху|Посередине|Посередь|Поскольку|После|Посреди|Посредине|Посредством|Пота|Потому|Почему|Почём|Правда|Пред|Предо|Прежде|При|Применительно|Притом|Причём|Про|Промеж|Просто|Против|Противу|Пускай|Пусть|Равно|Ради|Раз|Разве|Ровно|Рядом|С|Сверх|Сверху|Свыше|Середи|Сзади|Сиречь|Сколько|Следовательно|Следом|Словно|Смотря|Снизу|Со|Согласно|Спустя|Среди|Средь|Сродни|Столько|Судя|Супротив|Так|Также|Теперь|То|Тож|Тоже|Только|У|Хоть|Хотя|Чем|Через|Черезо|Чрез|Что|Чтоб|Чтобы|Чуть|Яко|Якобы)`