# Hard spaces after one-letter words in ConTeXt

Tags: context, typography

I am looking for a ConTeXt solution that will allow me to move single letters from the end to the beginning of the line.

LuaLaTeX has

https://ctan.org/pkg/luavlna or https://ctan.org/pkg/impnattypo packages

Algorithm in Lua

[one-letter word at the end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/one-letter-word-at-the-end-of-line)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can almost copy-paste the code from the linked answer, you just have to know where to put it.  (Also works in LMTX, at least in `2020.07.30 01:02`)

```
\startluacode
```

```lua
function userdata.prevent_single_letter(head)
    local cur = head
    while cur do
        if cur.id == node.id("glyph") then
            if cur.prev.id == node.id("glue") and cur.next.id == node.id("glue") then
                local p = node.new("penalty")
                p.penalty = 10000

                -- This is for debugging only, but then you have to
                -- remove the last node.insert_after line:
                --local w = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
                --w.data = "q 1 0 1 RG 1 0 1 rg 0 0 m 0 5 l 2 5 l 2 0 l b Q"
                --node.insert_after(head,cur,w)
                --node.insert_after(head,w,p)

                node.insert_after(head,cur,p)
            end
        end
        cur = cur.next
    end
    return head, true
end
```

```
\stopluacode

\mainlanguage[pl]

% Ugh ... don't do this for real
\noheaderandfooterlines
\setuplayout[width=8.2cm]
\setupwhitespace[big]

\starttext

Noc była sierpniowa, ciepła i słodka, Księżyc oświecał srebrnem światłem
wgłębienie, tak, że twarze małego rycerza i Basi były skąpane w blasku.
Poniżej, na podwórzu zamkowem, widać było uśpione kupy żołnierzy, a także i
ciała zabitych podczas dziennej strzelaniny, bo nie znaleziono dotąd czasu na
ich pogrzebanie.

\startluacode
```

```lua
nodes.tasks.appendaction("processors", "before", "userdata.prevent_single_letter")
```

```
\stopluacode

Noc była sierpniowa, ciepła i słodka, Księżyc oświecał srebrnem światłem
wgłębienie, tak, że twarze małego rycerza i Basi były skąpane w blasku.
Poniżej, na podwórzu zamkowem, widać było uśpione kupy żołnierzy, a także i
ciała zabitych podczas dziennej strzelaniny, bo nie znaleziono dotąd czasu na
ich pogrzebanie.

\stoptext
```

Red ellipses were added later
[image]