# ConTeXt: Non-breakable space finalizer crashes with \title

Tags: spacing, context

This is a follow-up question connected to this: [Non-breakable space after isolated one letter](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/517903/hard-spaces-after-one-letter-words-in-context)

After testing proposed solution on plain text, the `finalizer` works. However, after using it in document containing sectioning commands (`\title`, but even others) ConTeXt process crashes.

**MWE:**

```
\startluacode
function userdata.prevent_single_letter(head)
    local cur = head
    while cur do
        if cur.id == node.id("glyph") then
            if cur.prev.id == node.id("glue") and cur.next.id == node.id("glue") then
                local p = node.new("penalty")
                p.penalty = 10000

                -- This is for debugging only, but then you have to
                -- remove the last node.insert_after line:
                --local w = node.new("whatsit","pdf_literal")
                --w.data = "q 1 0 1 RG 1 0 1 rg 0 0 m 0 5 l 2 5 l 2 0 l b Q"
                --node.insert_after(head,cur,w)
                --node.insert_after(head,w,p)

                node.insert_after(head,cur,p)
            end
        end
        cur = cur.next
    end
    return head, true
end
\stopluacode

\startluacode
nodes.tasks.appendaction("processors", "before", "userdata.prevent_single_letter")
\stopluacode

\starttext
\title[title:poznamky]{Notes z Con\TeX{}t}

Filling text filling text filling text filling text filling text filling text filling text fil V text

\stoptext
```

Even more trubling is, that I am unable to get any meaningfull error message other than the issue is caused by `\title`. The only readable error message I am getting from console:

```
 hpack filter: error: [\directlua]:6: attempt to index a nil value (field 'prev')
```

I have no idea what is `hpack_filter`. In order to next time be able to debug issues I am hitting upon a little better, what reference for ConTeXt should I use?

Comment: Read LuaTeX reference manual, which is shipped with ConTeXt distribution (don't know if shipped with TeXlive). `hpack_filter` is described p. 173. Note that there are more than 50 manuals shipped with ConTeXt, so which one you should read depend on your issue.

Comment: Replace the conditional `if cur.prev.id == ...` by `if cur.prev and cur.next and cur.prev.id == ...`.  The problem here is that the `prev` field does not exist but it tries to index it anyway to get the `id` field which is not allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem comes from the fact that the ConTeXt `processors` run both on `pre_linebreak_filter` and on `hpack_filter`.  In `pre_linebreak_filter` the problem will not show up because the first node is always `local_par`.  In `hpack_filter`, however, the first node is very likely a `glyph` which is a problem because there will be no other node preceding it, i.e. the `prev` field is `nil`.  Right now the code just queries the `id` property of the `prev` field but since the `prev` field doesn't exist in the first place, this fails.  We can work around this by harnessing a property of the and logical `and` (and `or`) operator which is called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

More information on those callbacks in ConTeXt can be found in the manual [MkIV Hybrid Technology](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/hybrid.pdf), in particular the tables in Chapter 9 “Callbacks” ([source](https://github.com/contextgarden/context-mirror/blob/cbaeded86ee193677fe0cae364b564616557449d/doc/context/sources/general/manuals/hybrid/hybrid-callbacks.tex#L53-L67)).

## On short-circuit evaluation in Lua

The common idiom in Lua is to guard this access using a statement like

```lua
if cur.prev and cur.prev.id == ... then
```

When the left-hand side operand evaluates to `false`, the right-hand side operand *is not even evaluated* and the composite expression results in `false`.  This is because `false and <anything>` will always be `false` by Boolean logic, irregardless of the value of `<anything>`.

In Lua this idiom extends even further, because the language assigns a “truthiness” to all values.  The values `nil` and `false` are always considered “false-y” whereas everything else is considered “true-y” (in particular the integer values `0` and `1` both evaluate “true-y” even though you might expect `0` to be “false-y” as it is in C-like languages).  On top of that, a logical statement always returns the last operand that was evaluated.  This allows for constructs like

```
userdata = userdata or {}
```

which you see a lot in the ConTeXt core Lua code.  What this does is that it evaluates `userdata` and if this is `nil` (which is considered “false-y”) it evaluates the `{}` (which is considered “true-y”) and *returns the empty table from the expression* which is then assigned to `userdata`.  This is a great way to quickly write a guarded variable initialization which does nothing when the variable is already initialized.

## MWE

In the present case, we can actually fuse the two nested `if` statements together by using the short-circuit evaluation property of `and`.  This makes the code quite a bit more compact and you might gain an infinitesimal performance improvement.  What's probably more relevant for performance is caching the IDs of the `glyph` and `glue` nodes, because these never change.

```
\startluacode
local glyph_id = node.id("glyph")
local glue_id = node.id("glue")

function userdata.prevent_single_letter(head)
    local cur = head
    while cur do
        if cur.id == glyph_id and
           cur.prev and
           cur.next and
           cur.prev.id == glue_id and
           cur.next.id == glue_id
        then
            local p = node.new("penalty")
            p.penalty = 10000
            node.insert_after(head,cur,p)
        end
        cur = cur.next
    end
    return head, true
end
\stopluacode

\startluacode
nodes.tasks.appendaction("processors", "before", "userdata.prevent_single_letter")
\stopluacode

\starttext
\title[title:poznamky]{Notes z Con\TeX{}t}

Filling text filling text filling text filling text filling text filling text filling text fil V text

\stoptext
```

Comment: Thank you for informative addition how to program in Lua. Even though I have peeked through Lua Reference, these things I did not know. Only thing that confuses me a little is function `node.insert_after` and its arguments. I am looking at its description in LuaTeX reference. The argument `head` is first node in (current) node list? But if I undersand it correctly, you are assigning current node into `head` and them using it in `node.insert_after(head,cur,p)`. Maybe I just dont know what `head` arg. stands for. I admit that last time I was reading LuaTeX ref. i didnt made it far

Comment: @TomášKruliš Well, that's complicated.  In fact, `head` is only a pointer to the head of the node list, so when assigning it to `cur` I'm only copying the pointer and not the actual head.  Hence, when incrementing `cur`, `head` will stay at the head of the list such that in the call `node.insert_after(head,cur,p)` both `head` and `cur` will point to the head and the current node, respectively.

Comment: @TomášKruliš I've found the source of the problem and updated the answer text.