# Troubles with listings and polish characters (lualatex)

Tags: pdftex, luatex, listings, input-encodings, polish

How I can display properly polish characters in code of programming language using `listings` package and `lualatex` compiler?

**main.cpp:**

```
//Zażółć gęślą jaźń

#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
  return 0;
}
```

**main.tex:**

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\babelprovide[transforms = oneletter.nobreak]{polish} 

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,   
    extendedchars=true, 
    tabsize=2
}


\lstset{style=mystyle}

\hbadness=99999 

\begin{document}
    
\lstinputlisting[language=C++]{main.cpp}

\end{document}
```

First result (`lualatex`):

[image: lualatex]

My goal is to have the result, as the picture below (in `lualatex` compile):

[image: goal]

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: don't use `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` with lualatex.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Fact! Now, after that suggestion, I have something like this: [link to current result](https://i.imgur.com/Vw3ZkQO.png)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer What do You think about it?

Comment: Actually the oneletter.nobreak feature requires lualatex [typography - one-letter word at the end of line - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/one-letter-word-at-the-end-of-line/650146#650146) -- removing that features it works with pdflatex.

Comment: Suggestion: Edit your question to adjust for omitting fontenc with LuaLatex AND your screenshot (i.e. resolve the link, as it may vanish over time).

Comment: @MS-SPO Sorry, but I don't understand You... I must remove a `fontenc` ?

Comment: See your comment on Ulrike's hint, a feww comments above.

Comment: @MS-SPO Hmm... I removed in my code, but I understand, that I must do also in a question version?

Comment: It's a suggestion. If you follow our approach, that 1 question = 1 problem, and each answer = 1 solution, and take into account that relevant information might get lost in a chain of comments ... it's natural to add what's relevant. Makes problems/questions more efficient to re-use by other people: all relevant infos in one place (only).

Comment: @MS-SPO Aaa... okeeey... I got it... I will try do this in a future. Thanks, and sorry for a trouble...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/138189/discussion-between-constantin-d-and-ms-spo).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few bugs here.

1. In pdflatex the `transforms = oneletter.nobreak` babel option is not supported. So you must use lualatex (or remove that feature)
2. In lualatex **do not use fontenc or inputenc**. (by the way you don't have to use inputenc in newer versions [Is there any reason to use inputenc?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/370278/250119))  In this particular case you must remove fontenc for it to work. (alternatively add both fontenc and literate works, but why bother?)
3. `listings` has some bugs that doesn't allow it to handle characters with codepoint > 255. This half of the question is duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25396/250119. Use the fix there

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[polish]{babel}
\babelprovide[transforms = oneletter.nobreak]{polish} 

\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\makeatletter
\lst@InputCatcodes
\def\lst@DefEC{%
 \lst@CCECUse \lst@ProcessLetter
  ^^80^^81^^82^^83^^84^^85^^86^^87^^88^^89^^8a^^8b^^8c^^8d^^8e^^8f%
  ^^90^^91^^92^^93^^94^^95^^96^^97^^98^^99^^9a^^9b^^9c^^9d^^9e^^9f%
  ^^a0^^a1^^a2^^a3^^a4^^a5^^a6^^a7^^a8^^a9^^aa^^ab^^ac^^ad^^ae^^af%
  ^^b0^^b1^^b2^^b3^^b4^^b5^^b6^^b7^^b8^^b9^^ba^^bb^^bc^^bd^^be^^bf%
  ^^c0^^c1^^c2^^c3^^c4^^c5^^c6^^c7^^c8^^c9^^ca^^cb^^cc^^cd^^ce^^cf%
  ^^d0^^d1^^d2^^d3^^d4^^d5^^d6^^d7^^d8^^d9^^da^^db^^dc^^dd^^de^^df%
  ^^e0^^e1^^e2^^e3^^e4^^e5^^e6^^e7^^e8^^e9^^ea^^eb^^ec^^ed^^ee^^ef%
  ^^f0^^f1^^f2^^f3^^f4^^f5^^f6^^f7^^f8^^f9^^fa^^fb^^fc^^fd^^fe^^ff%
żłćęśąźń%
  ^^00}
\lst@RestoreCatcodes
\makeatother

\definecolor{codegreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{codegray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{codepurple}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}
\definecolor{backcolour}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.92}

\lstdefinestyle{mystyle}{
    backgroundcolor=\color{backcolour},   
    commentstyle=\color{codegreen},
    keywordstyle=\color{magenta},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{codegray},
    stringstyle=\color{codepurple},
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize,
    breakatwhitespace=false,         
    breaklines=true,                 
    captionpos=b,                    
    keepspaces=true,                 
    numbers=left,                    
    numbersep=5pt,                  
    showspaces=false,                
    showstringspaces=false,
    showtabs=false,   
    extendedchars=true, 
    tabsize=2
}


\lstset{style=mystyle}

\hbadness=99999 

\begin{document}

\noindent Przetestujmy możliwości języka C++, oraz wiszące litery na końcu zdania i coś tam jeszcze: \newline

\lstinputlisting[language=C++]{main.cpp}

\end{document}
```

Seems to work for me.

(as you can probably infer, include every character with codepoint > 255 once in addition to the existing. You can also use the `^^^^<4 digits>` or `^^^^^^<6 digits>` notation to specify by hex code.)

Comment: Ouch... I understand... thanks a lot! By the way, I added big letters to Your code, and it works perfectly!

Comment: I edited a question, as MS-SPO tried to explain me ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just for comparison. What we can do with [OpTeX](https://petr.olsak.net/optex/):

```
\fontfam[lm]
\hsize=10cm

\noindent
Przetestujmy możliwości języka C++, oraz wiszące litery na końcu zdania i coś tam jeszcze:

\verbinput \hisyntax{C} (-) main.cpp

\bye
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Wow, that's so cool!

Comment: Suggestion: Please Edit this solution and explain it a little bit more, at least what you mean by OpTex. Not everybody is familiar with it, and some more context won't hurt.

Comment: @MS-SPO Fact, I didn't use it earlier... (I mean OpTeX)