# Excluding words that cannot be at the end of a line

Tags: line-breaking

haven't found this topic on any LaTeX forum in my surprise. So I hope it's not completely stupid idea or I didn't use wrong tags.

To expand the idea in the title, is there a way to set up a set of words that are not allowed to be at the end of the line (e.g. *the*,*a*,*of* etc...)? A similar thing is hyphenation. I found some functions or the *hyphenat* package, but it says that if the *babel* is used, it overrides the nohyphenation setting.
Is there a way of setting this or maybe creating set of these words manually?

Thank you for any notes on this

Comment: standard tex can not do this. luatex could match the input buffer changing space to `~` before such words. I think some language options may do this, it's not normally an issue in English

Comment: several answers on this site eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/one-letter-word-at-the-end-of-line

Comment: Spell checking and grammar checking are usually handled by the editor.

Comment: Implementation of something similar is in the luavlna package intended for LuaTeX.