# Single character at end of line

Tags: line-breaking, typography, impnattypo

I am looking for a way to discourage ending lines with a single character. I could manually type out, for example: `a\penalty\hyphenpenalty\ cat` or `I\nolinebreak[1]\ am` each time I write a single character, but I am looking for an automated solution. I am aware that regex workarounds exist.

I have read another discussion on this forum where ending a line with a single character is absolutely prohibited rather than simply discouraged. (Compare `I~am` with `I\nolinebreak[1]\ am`.)
[one-letter word at the end of line](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/27780/one-letter-word-at-the-end-of-line)
I have tested this in my other documents via `\usepackage[nosingleletter]{impnattypo}`. I have found that it is more likely than not typographically inferior to alternatively discouraging line breaks at single characters.

Comment: use the accepted answer that you link to but change `p.penalty = 10000` to `p.penalty = 100` or whatever penalty you want

Comment: I ended up just slightly modifying the `impnattypo` package as you suggested. Not the most elegant method, but it achieves the intended result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the accepted answer that you link to but change

```
p.penalty = 10000
```

to

```
p.penalty = 100
```

or whatever penalty you want, so that breaking is discouraged rather than prevented. You could suggest to the author of `impnattypo` that the value is made available via a package option or command, defaulting to 10000.